# Laravel Vite doesn't seem to find or bundle app.js file

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite, laravel-filament, laravel-vite

I'm using Laravel 10 in a Filament project with vite. I have pretty much the stock vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/css/filament/app/theme.css'
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Filament/**',
                'app/Forms/Components/**',
                'app/Livewire/**',
                'app/Infolists/Components/**',
                'app/Providers/Filament/**',
                'app/Tables/Columns/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
})
```

I have this in my blade layout file in the head:

`@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])`

In my `resources/js/app.js` file I have this:

```
console.log('test');
import JSConfetti from 'js-confetti';

const jsConfetti = new JSConfetti();
window.jsConfetti = jsConfetti;

console.log('jsConfetti is set', window.jsConfetti);
```

I've run `npm run build`, but I don't even get the simple "test" message from the console.log statement in app.js. It almost seems like vite isn't loading the app.js file at all. I should at the very least see the "test" message from app.js, right?

I upgraded the laravel-vite plugin to 1.0.1 and upgraded vite to 5.0.0, but that hasn't resolved it either. I've cleared the cache and hard refreshed. I've verified that jsConfetti is in my node_modules folder.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I see in the sources tab in dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Did you check sources if you can see app.js? Can you check if the changes made were reflected?

Comment: Maybe the js files were cached and you need to empty cache and reload to redownload them. If so, adding an asset version should help when changing assets. If not, then problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth It's my understanding that vite handles the asset versioning, but I probably need to look into whether that happens on `npm run dev` or not. Regardless, I've cleared the cache and hard reloaded multiple times with no change. It's like my app.js file doesn't even exist.